# Publish Git Comments / Releases to Site (Continuous Deployment)

Tags: php, git, github, semantic-versioning, axosoft

Sorry if title isn't correct.  I'm trying to figure out what to search for on this matter.

I'm looking for the easiest way to automatically have my [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) and commits visible on my site when commits / releases happen.

I recently started using Git, GitHub, GitFlow, Axosoft, and GitKraken.    Are there any options, plugins, or RSS type feeds in those products that do this already or is this something I would have to create using Git webhooks which would call my site and insert into my DB?

I can handle the PHP/MySQL.  I'm just looking for recommendations on how to setup the communication between the products I listed above so that I can create a PHP page showing this to my customers...

- [timestamp] - RELEASE v2.1.1
- [timestamp] - [axof: 2] ENHANCED XYZ [...a sentence or two of details...]
- [timestamp] - RELEASE v2.0.1
- [timestamp] - [axof: 1] BUG ABC FIXED [...a sentence or two of details...]

Comment: This would be a good question for the [DevOps exchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/tags).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Can you post an answer to your own question?

Comment: @jwdonahue , not yet I haven't.  I had to move on to other tasks but will be revisiting this soon and will post any helpful updates then.